# How to write a transaction in DAO class of Spring ibatis

Tags: java, mysql, performance, ibatis

How to write a transaction in Spring Ibatis DAO implementation class.

I am using following code for batch update.But it is taking more than 10seconds to update 200 records.When i searched in google i found that it will work faster if we implement the transaction in this batch update.

My batch update code is like this (in the class SensorValueLastBeanDAOImpl)

```
public int processBatchUpdate(
        final List<SensorValueLastBean> sensorValueLast) {

    Integer updateCount = 0;
    try {


        updateCount = (Integer) getSqlMapClientTemplate().execute(
                new SqlMapClientCallback<Object>() {
                    public Object doInSqlMapClient(SqlMapExecutor executor)
                            throws SQLException {                                           
                        executor.startBatch();
                        Iterator<SensorValueLastBean> iter = sensorValueLast
                                .iterator();
                        while (iter.hasNext()) {
                            executor.update(
                                    "sensor_values_last.ibatorgenerated_updateByPrimaryKeySelective",
                                    iter.next());
                        }
                                                                                    executor.executeBatch();
                        return new Integer(executor.executeBatch());

                    }
                });
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

when i used getSqlMapClient().startTransaction() in this function it is showing an error like below

> java.lang.NullPointerException     at
>   com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.impl.SqlMapExecutorDelegate.startTransaction(SqlMapExecutorDelegate.java:684)
>   at
>   com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.impl.SqlMapSessionImpl.startTransaction(SqlMapSessionImpl.java:164)
>   at
>   com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.impl.SqlMapClientImpl.startTransaction(SqlMapClientImpl.java:140)

Answer (score 0):

The second error occured because there is no transaction manager for ibatis. You can configure as the following.

```
<!DOCTYPE sqlMapConfig
PUBLIC "-//ibatis.apache.org//DTD SQL Map Config 2.0//EN" 
"http://ibatis.apache.org/dtd/sql-map-config-2.dtd">

<sqlMapConfig>
  <settings useStatementNamespaces="true"/>
    <transactionManager type="JDBC">
      <dataSource type="SIMPLE">
      <property name="JDBC.Driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
      <property name="JDBC.ConnectionURL"
      value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb"/>
      <property name="JDBC.Username" value="root"/>
      <property name="JDBC.Password" value="root"/>
    </dataSource>
 </transactionManager>
<sqlMap resource="Contact.xml"/>
```